What's the policy on DN42/CRXN?
DN42 is a toy model of the Internet, using real Internet protocols such as BGP, over VPN links which simulate physical ones. There are other similar networks such as CRXN. Since they mimic the Internet, real enterprise-like/service-provider-like questions emerge, such as around address space planning and routing policy - with the main difference being that few people complain if something is down.
Are questions arising from toy internets on-topic? The same question could be asked about the real internet, after all. I think they're equivalent to lab scenarios, which is on-topic.

Sorry, late answer, but our topics list pretty much says it all - most prominently


operating, maintaining, purchasing or managing an enterprise / service provider network;


So, if that overlay network is in regular use, then it's on topic here. I guess that is not the case.
However, if the use scenario is the same as on the normal Internet and you have full control over the network in question, then it should be on topic here. Make sure you read and understand what our community has decided to discuss here, linked at the top.

These overlay networks are intended to simulate the internet, but are not in "serious" use because people with "serious" uses just use the normal internet. You wouldn't find an accounting firm with a presence on either DN42 or CRXN (or AnoNet etc, nor any other non-internet-like network such as Tor or Yggdrasil). Most participants are running service-provider-like or enterprise-like networks, but don't actually provide services to paying customers.
